# Fetch all values from only one specific field in an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have a PHP function that displays all active membership levels

WordPress Plugin: Paid Membership Pro.
Function: function pmpro_getMembershipLevelsForUser()
Reference: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/function-to-retrieve-multiple-levels-from-user

```
function helpdesksupporthq($user) {
  $userId = $user->ID;
  $membership_level_details = pmpro_getMembershipLevelsForUser ( $userId );
  $level_id = $membership_level_details;
  print_r($level_id);
}
```

Current Output

```
Array ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 3 [id] => 3 [subscription_id] => 1 **[name] => SupportA** [description] =>  [confirmation] => [expiration_number] => 0 [expiration_period] => 0 [initial_payment] => 199 [billing_amount] => 199 [cycle_number] => 1 [cycle_period] => Year [billing_limit] => 0 [trial_amount] => 0 [trial_limit] => 0 [code_id] => 0 [startdate] => 1707000062 [enddate] => ) 
  [1] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 5 [id] => 5
```

Could you please guide me on how to display all values of a specific field [name] from the given data?

Example: [name] -- SupportA

Correct Output:

SupportA
SupportB
SupportC

Thanks!

Comment: `foreach ($membership_level_details as $membership) { echo $membership->name; }` . Did you try anything or research anything? This is pretty bog-standard stuff.